# Iterate through pairs in a python list and update the list and pairs during iteration, restarting the iteration at N-1 places

Tags: python, list, iterable

Hi I am trying to make a code that iterates over pairs in a list that looks  like this.

```
List=[A1,A2,A4,A5,E3,A3,E1,A7,E2,E3]
```

if the condition is met (E before A) something will be done and the pairs will  update. In this case, the pair (E3, A3) will be switched and the new order will be ( A3,E3) and then the new list will be:

```
List=[A1,A2,A4,A5,E3,A3,E1,A7,E2,E3] <--Initial
List=[A1,A2,A4,A5,A3,E3,E1,A7,E2,E3]  <--Switched
```

After the switch, I want the iterations to restart over in the new list(Switched List) from the last pair of two A's of the list before the switch (Initial list), (A4, A5), or from the first pair, (A1,A2), of elements. Always trying to keep the lowest complexity O(N) and fastest performance possible.

This is what I have so far:

```
def pairwise(ListX):
"Pairs -> (A1,A2), (A2,A4), (A4, A5),(A5, E3),(E3, A3),(A3, E1), ..."
  a = iter(ListX)
  b = iter(ListX)
  next(b, None)
  return izip(a, b)

for a, b in pairwise(List):
  if a!= b and a == 'E':
   #do something and switch positions
```

An input list could be:

```
  List_test=[AA_c,AA_A,AE_b,AA_w,AE_x,AE_Y,AA_P,AE_Q]
```

Here the condition to check is if AE_* is before a AA_* an implementation of this rutine is:

```
def AE_looking(Pointer,List_test,Dict): 
 Final=[]
 New=[] 
 for a, b in pairwise(List_test):
   if a[:2] != b[:2] and a[:2] == 'AE':
        Final2=Final[:]

        New.append(Action(a,b)) #Action is another rutine that takes a and b and gives C.
        New.extend(Final)
        List_test[:]=filter(lambda x: x not in Final, List_test)
        List_test.remove(a)
        List_test.remove(b)

        Final2.append(b)
        Final2.append(a)
        Final2.extend(List_test)
        New.extend(List_test)
        List_test[:]=Final2

        ###Add element to a dictionary 

        Dict.update({len(Dict):New[:]})
        Dict.update({Pointer:Oper_list[:]})
        New[:]=[]
        Final.append(b)


   if a[:2] != b[:2] and a[:2] != 'AE':
       Final.append(a)
   if a[:2] == b[:2]:
       Final.append(a)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are `A1` etc. strings or other objects?

Comment: they are strings, but could be larger than just 2 characters, e.g. ADEEDAD12

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and include some real Python code for the input.

Comment: I did edit the post using a more real example.